# How do I append an obj to a static lib?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I already have a static lib which generated by Visual Studio 2019.
Let say it is a.lib.
How do I append an obj (new.obj) to a.lib ?

Can LIB.exe do that for me ?
If so, how to do that ?

Comment: `link.exe -lib a.lib new.obj`

Comment: Most command line tools show a brief help when called without any argument. (At least the good ones.) Did you try that? Additionally I would expect that you read the documentation of your tools.